# num lock messing up keys on right side of keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, keys, layout, numlock

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on a HP Pavillion DV9700 laptop.

This use to work fine (for years)  I have had 14.04 running for at least 3-4 months.  This problem just started a couple weeks ago, not sure if it is something that got updated or what happened.

When my numlock is on so I can use my numberpad on the right side of my keyboard it messes up the right side of my letter keys.  Before, I could use all 27 letters plus , . / with num lock on.

Now when num lock is on  keys on left give result on right

Keys = result

890-  = 89/-

uiop   = 456*

jkl; = 123-

nm, = n0,

How/What changes do I need to make so that the letter keys always use the letters (like it use to) when numlock is on or off?

About this time, my screenshot stopped working and I changed the hotkeys to make a screenshot, but I can not find anything to fix this issue.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As your keyboard has a separate numberpad, this is likely a hardware/firmware problem, and is not because of Ubuntu.  Many people have reported the same thing happening in Windows with similar models of laptop.  See http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/Problem-with-num-lock-and-keyboard/td-p/256, for example.

Put simply, your keyboard firmware now wrongly thinks that it doesn't have a numberpad, and these keys can be used as a numberpad on keyboards without one.